# ES6 exit function from inside another function callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the function:

```
function addUser(request) {
return new Promise((res, rej) => {

    ValidateFormData(request, CREATE_USER, (err) => {if(err) return rej(makeError(err)) });
    console.log('creating user');
    res();
})
```

}

How can I stop the function when `ValidateFormData` callback contains `err` so that `console.log('creating user');` won't execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to put that stuff in the `else` branch inside that callback:

```
function addUser(request) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        ValidateFormData(request, CREATE_USER, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                rej(makeError(err));
            } else {
                console.log('creating user');
                res();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Putting it outside of the asynchronous callback (regardless whether outside of `ValidateFormData`, or even outside `new Promise`) will cause it to run immediately, and you won't have a chance to prevent it retroactively when the error has occurred in the future.

Alternatively, use a `then` callback to process the result, if there's more than a simple log() that cannot fail:

```
function addUser(request) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        ValidateFormData(request, CREATE_USER, (err) => {
            if (err) rej(makeError(err));
            else res();
        });
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('creating user');
        …
    });
}
```

This is especially useuful as it allows to just [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) your `ValidateFormData` function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put everything inside the callback where you can control the code flow of execution and use an if/else for the `err`:

```
function addUser(request) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {

        ValidateFormData(request, CREATE_USER, (err) => {
            if(err) {
                rej(makeError(err));
            } else {
                console.log('creating user');
                res();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Keep in mind that you can also use `util.promisify()` to convert async callback functions into promise returning functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
ValidateFormData(request, CREATE_USER, (err) => {if(err) return rej(makeError(err)) });
console.log('creating user');
```

assuming that the `ValidateFormData` function is async (most likely is, since you have a callback), the following `console.log` does not wait on it to finish.
Hence, it will run whether or not `ValidateFormData` completes or not.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript executes asynchronously, that is why `console.log("creating user")` gets executed before the callback function in `ValidateFormData`. Put your `console.log` in the callback function and everything will be fine.

```js
function addUser(request) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    ValidateFormData(request, CREATE_USER, (err) => {
      if(err) { 
        return rej(makeError(err)) 
      }
    console.log('creating user'); 
   });
}
```